# Realistic expectations from a postdoc in terms of publications

Tags: publications, funding, postdocs

I am in the process of applying for a postdoctoral grant and I was wondering what the expectations are in terms of journal publications when I plan?

Would it be fine if I plan 1 paper per year if I have no PhD students? Is 2 papers/year an exaggeration?

Input from senior members, possibly those with selection committee experiences would be great.

Field: engineering (electrical and electronic)
Country: Australia, EU, USA

Comment: Which field, which country?

Comment: Apart from your specific subfield, this also depends on the nature of your research project and several other factors. For example, some kinds of projects tend to result in several small publications while others result in a single large one. I therefore do not think that anybody who is not familiar with your specific project can give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 4):

One per year may appear unambitious. I suggest framing them in terms of 1/year 'sure bet' publications and additional 'reach goal' publications, to show a balance of ambition and realism.